# core dumps for out of memory in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash, core-dump

How to create memory dumps for out of memory.

If system is out of memory then oom-killer kills the process which occupies highest memory by some calculations.

How can we get core dump of the process killed

Answer (score 3):

Even if your kernel was configured to generate a core dump, the OOM killer would not cause a core dump to be produced because it sends a SIGKILL.

As decribed in [signal's man page (7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), SIGKILL does not produce a core dump.

The only way to change that behavior would therefore require a custom patch to the kernel.

Comment: Can we get crash dump? Tried to configure /etc/sysctl.conf with following parameter. vm.panic_on_oom=1 but it didn't work

Comment: I am able to get crash dumps when I have used the custom c script for OOM which is present in this link https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-reboot-on-oom/ . But when kernel triggers oom-killer to kill the highest used process(kernel logs are observed in /var/log/kern.log), it is not triggering the panic signal. Is it because of kernel libraries? Does any patch needs to be applied in kernel to trigger  panic signals.

Comment: Like I mentioned, you'd need to change the signal sent and enable core dumps in your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Configured vm.panic_on_oom=2 in /etc/sysctl.conf, which solves my problem.
```

**

- panic_on_oom

**

This enables or disables panic on out-of-memory feature.

If this is set to 0, the kernel will kill some rogue process,
called oom_killer.  Usually, oom_killer can kill rogue processes and
system will survive.

If this is set to 1, the kernel panics when out-of-memory happens.
However, if a process limits using nodes by mempolicy/cpusets,
and those nodes become memory exhaustion status, one process
may be killed by oom-killer. No panic occurs in this case.
Because other nodes' memory may be free. This means system total status
may be not fatal yet.

If this is set to 2, the kernel panics compulsorily even on the
above-mentioned. Even oom happens under memory cgroup, the whole
system panics.

The default value is 0.
1 and 2 are for failover of clustering. Please select either
according to your policy of failover.
panic_on_oom=2+kdump gives you very strong tool to investigate
why oom happens. You can get snapshot.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt